# How to run Facebook Social Plugin Javascript From CodeBehind C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook, dialog, code-behind

I have a website where i want my visitors to invite their friends. I'm using the Requests Dialog for this. But now i want to add a dynamic text message to this invite.

The dynamic text is generated in an c# code behind file. But the Request Dialog is triggered with javascript.

Here is the Request Dialog part on my aspx page:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
      FB.init({
          appId: '[MY-APP-ID]', cookie: true,
          status: true, xfbml: true
      });

      function inviteFriends() {
          FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: '[THE DYNAMIC MESSAGE I WANT TO SEND]', data: 'tracking information for the user' });
      }


  </script>
```

Is it possible to call this javascript form codebehind code and pass the message parameter too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<%= ... %>` to expose your code to page (assuming you have message in `requestsDialogMessage` variable):

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: '<%= requestsDialogMessage %>',
  data: 'tracking information for the user'
});
```

Other way may be exposing the message to some JavaScript variable and using it within `FB.ui` call:

```
<script>
  var exposedData = {
    requestsDialogMessage: '<%= requestsDialogMessage %>'
  };
</script>
```

And later in your JS code:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: exposedData.requestsDialogMessage,
  data: 'tracking information for the user'
});
```

Comment: I dont need this anymore but i believe your answer will do the trick :)

Comment: @ThomasDekiere, Probably you can wait couple of hours/days/"until confirmed" just to be nice ;)